# MS SQL removes newly inserted row automatically straight after insert

Tags: sql-server

I have a weird issue. In the MSSQL database I have multiple tables in that database but only two of them does this:

1. I insert a new row
2. get row count (which is increased by 1)
3. get row count again within seconds (this time it's decreased) and the new row is not in the table anymore

The query i use to insert row and get count:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CSMobileMessages]
           ([MessageSID],[IssueID],[UserSent])
     VALUES
        ('213',0,'blabla')

SELECT count([IDx])
  FROM [dbo].[CSMobileMessages]
```

The SQL query returns "1 row affected" and i even get back the new row ID as well from the identity column. No errors at all. I checked in profiler which states 1 row inserted successfully and nothing else happened.
The table has no triggers. Index only on identity field (IDx), user used is "sa" with full access. Tried with different user but same happens.

The table is called "CSMobileMessages" so I created a new table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CSMobileMessages2](
    [IDx] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MessageSID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IssueID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserSent] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CSMobileMessages2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDx] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CSMobileMessages2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_CSMobileMessages2_IssueID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IssueID]
GO
```

I insert 1000 rows into the new table and it worked. So i delete the old table (CSMobileMessages) and rename the new table from CSMobileMessages2 to CSMobileMessages.
As soon as i do that, the inserted rows gets deleted and i will get the exact same row count for the new table what i had with the old one. Also i can't insert rows anymore. No services or any other software touches this table. However if i restart the server i can insert 1 new row and after it starts happening again.

Edit:
I uses MSSMS and connect to the database remotely but i tried locally on the server as well and same happens. A service used this table but i disabled it when this started few days ago. Before that the service ran happily for 1 year with no issue. I double checked to make sure, the service is turned off and no one connects to that table but me.

Has anyone ever seen this issue before and knows what causes it?

Comment: Have you uncommitted transaction active?

Comment: No, i just ran a query to check it after i insert but no open transactions

Comment: SQL Server won't remove anything by itself. Either you have an uncommitted transaction or custom code runs and deletes that row. We can't guess what's going on in that database. Perhaps you connect to the wrong database?  Are you using LocalDB or a user instance database that gets overwritten every time your application or web site starts?

Comment: Actually it does sometimes with corrupt index for example. I run this from MSSMS. I connect to the right database remotely but tried on the server locally and same happens. No other application uses that table now. Actually a service used it before but i disabled that service few days ago when this started.

Comment: About corrupt index - dbcc checkdb returns no errors, yes? If you watch all your session with SQL Profiler (you may select events like SP Stmt started and SP Stmt completed, also Exceptions), does something reveal itself?

Comment: _Actually a service used it before but i disabled that service few days ago when this started_ This is the only clue in this post about what the issue could be. Something else is deleting that row. You could try putting an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger to try and catch it or you could try using extended events to try and capture what is going on

Comment: I tried but it's not triggered. It seems for some reason after up to few secs whatever i do with that table it gets rolled back. However i don't use roll back neither transact not even in the service (which btw disabled). Its bit like something gone wrong with the index or the table or whatever and it stuck in a state and SQL keeps roll it back to the original state but i can't find anything.

Comment: I suggest you use extended events to capture what is going on. You also mention profiler in your explanation. You can use that to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and the whole database was reset from few days old back up as a last try and it's working now as it supposed to. I don't set this question as answered because even it's fixed the problem I still have no idea what happened exactly as within my 20+ yrs coding i never seen anything like this before.
Thanks for everyone who tried to help with ideas!